# Integer to binary conversions in dev c++

Tags: c++, binary, int, type-conversion

I have only learned about gets,puts,printf,scanf, if, else if,for loop, while loop, and array. How to solve this problem ? im using basic c++ only.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() { 
   int i,r,j,num,binari[8]; 
   scanf("%d",&num); 
   for(i=0;num>=0;i++) { 
      if(num%2==1) 
         binari[i]=num%2; 
      if (num%2==0) 
         { binari[i]=num%2; } 
      num=num/2; 
    } 
    for (j=i;j>=0;j--) {
       printf("%d",binari[j]); 
    } 
    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please go do more research and read books and articles. Stackoverflow won't do your homework.

Comment: what is wrong here ?


#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

     int i,r,j,num,binari[8];
     scanf("%d",&num);  
     for(i=0;num>=0;i++)
     {    
         
         if(num%2==1)
         binari[i]=num%2;
         if (num%2==0)
         {
         binari[i]=num%2;
         }
         num=num/2;
     }   
         
         
  
         
            
           
           
     
     
     
     for (j=i;j>=0;j--) 
     {
     printf("%d",binari[j]);
     }
     system("pause");
     return 0;
}

Comment: Edit your question and add the code with a proper formatting, based on the guidelines and explain what is not working and what error you get (if you've already searched for the error without finding anything relevant). We can't say "What is wrong here".

Comment: binary is a bit too small. `2^8 = 256`. Any number above that will cause an undefined behavior. You need to use a variable array container or a bitset if you want to save the value. Or you can just print it as you go.

Comment: Btw, what is the problem you have? What input did you enter and how does it differ from what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

To convert integer value to its ASCII binary code, there are many ways. I used the manual way (the same way you would do it on paper):

```
int DecToBin(int N) {
    int multiplier = 1; // For arranging digits like: 1*(once digit) + 10*(tens digit) + ...
    
    int finalBin = 0; // Final output
    
    // Loop for continuous division by 2, to find remainders and making finalBin number using the digits:
    while (N >= 1){     
        int digit = N & 1; // Getting the binary digit

        N >>= 1;  // N = N/2 for next iteration

        finalBin += digit * multiplier; // NUMBER = ONCE*1 TENS*10 THOUSANDS*1000 + ...

        multiplier *= 10; // 1 10 10 1000 ...
    }

    return finalBin;
}
```